# Scala and Spark UDF function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I made a simple UDF to convert or extract some values from a time field in a temptabl in spark. I register the function but when I call the function using sql it throws a NullPointerException. Below is my function and process of executing it. I am using Zeppelin. Strangly this was working yesterday but it stopped working this morning.

Function

```
def convert( time:String ) : String = {
  val sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
  val time1 = sdf.parse(time)
  return sdf.format(time1)
}
```

Register the Function

```
sqlContext.udf.register("convert",convert _)
```

Test the function without SQL -- This works

```
convert(12:12:12) -> returns 12:12
```

Test the function with SQL in Zeppelin this FAILS.

```
%sql
select convert(time) from temptable limit 10
```

Structure of temptable

```
root
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- serverip: string (nullable = true)
 |-- request: string (nullable = true)
 |-- resource: string (nullable = true)
 |-- protocol: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- sourceip: string (nullable = true)
```

Part of the stacktrace that I am getting.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.getFunctionInfo(FunctionRegistry.java:643)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry.getFunctionInfo(FunctionRegistry.java:652)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveFunctionRegistry.lookupFunction(hiveUdfs.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$3.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$OverrideFunctionRegistry$$super$lookupFunction(HiveContext.scala:376)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$lookupFunction$2.apply(FunctionRegistry.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$lookupFunction$2.apply(FunctionRegistry.scala:44)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideFunctionRegistry$class.lookupFunction(FunctionRegistry.scala:44)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use udf instead of define a function directly

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val convert = udf[String, String](time => {
        val sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
        val time1 = sdf.parse(time)
        sdf.format(time1)
    }
)
```

A udf's input parameter is Column(or Columns). And the return type is Column.

```
case class UserDefinedFunction protected[sql] (
    f: AnyRef,
    dataType: DataType,
    inputTypes: Option[Seq[DataType]]) {

  def apply(exprs: Column*): Column = {
    Column(ScalaUDF(f, dataType, exprs.map(_.expr), inputTypes.getOrElse(Nil)))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to define your function as a UDF.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val convertUDF: UserDefinedFunction = udf((time:String) => {
  val sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
  val time1 = sdf.parse(time)
  sdf.format(time1)
})
```

Next you would apply your UDF on your DataFrame.

```
// assuming your DataFrame is already defined
dataFrame.withColumn("time", convertUDF(col("time"))) // using the same name replaces existing
```

Now, as to your actual problem, one reason you are receiving this error could be because your DataFrame contains rows which are nulls. If you filter them out before you apply the UDF, you should be able to continue no problem.

```
dataFrame.filter(col("time").isNotNull)
```

I'm curious what else causes a NullPointerException when running a UDF other than it encountering a null, if you found a reason different than my suggestion, I'd be glad to know.

Comment: Can i define that convertUDF in a different scala class  and import that  scala class in another package to use that UDF?

Comment: @SurenderRaja I don't see any reason against it. It's a standalone function. Are you facing any particular difficulty?

Comment: @SurenderRaja Maybe if you use a singleton object, that might be simpler.

Comment: Yes, I created a singleton Scala object  and defined a a method inside that all my UDFS , it worked