# Spark create UDF that doesn't take in input

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I want to add a column with a randomly generated id to my Spark dataframe. To do that, I'm using a UDF to call UUID's random UUID method, like so:

```
def getRandomId(s:String) : String = {
    UUID.randomUUID().toString()
}

val idUdf = udf(getRandomId(_:String))
val newDf = myDf.withColumn("id", idUdf($"colName"))
```

Obviously, my getRandomId function does not need an input parameter; however, I can't figure out how to create a UDF that does not take in a column as input. Is that possible in Spark?

I am using Spark 1.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala and Spark UDF function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633216/scala-and-spark-udf-function)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can register udf with no params. Here `() => String` will solve the requirement

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val uuid = udf(() => java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString)
```

using the UDF(`uuid`) on DataFrame

```
val newDf = myDf.withColumn("uuid", uuid())
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It's exactly what I was looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
def getRandomId() : String = {
   UUID.randomUUID().toString()
}

val idUdf = udf(getRandomId _)
val newDf = df.withColumn("id", idUdf())
```

The trick is `getRandomId _` creates a Function `() => String` out of your method